# Find usage of a particular method when called with a particular subtype

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, code-analysis

I'm refactoring the nasty out of a largeish codebase and need to find where a particular method, accepting instances of a fairly general interface, is called with a particular implementation of that interface.

For example, in the `NastyStatic` is the `DoBadThings(IBusinessObject)` method. I have about 50 classes that implement `IBusinessObject` in my business library, including `DontHurtMe : IBusinessObject`.

How can I find every call to `NastyStatic.DoBadThings(foo)`, but only where `foo` is an instance of `DontHurtMe`?

EDIT: I'm after some sort of static analysis tool. Setting a dynamic watch in `DoBadThings` (or similar) and running the application isn't really an option. It will already throw an exception due to changes I've made to `DontHurtMe`, and there are far too many code paths to find all usages that way (at least until it goes live and my users start complaining).

Comment: I'd be surprised (and very interested) if an anwser that does not include adding some kind of tracing to the DoBadThings method and running the application exists

Comment: @xorcrud that's exactly what I want to avoid too ;-) there's too many code paths, and it already throws an exception in that case anyway

Comment: How would it help you to refactor it anyway?

Comment: @Dyppl I want to stop using `NastyStatic.DoBadThings` completely and replace it with repo calls, but there is too much involved in just dropping `DoBadThings` with all 50 or so business classes. There are thousands of calls like this through the system. I'm just refactoring one business class at a time as I need to.

Comment: What if all of the callers of DoBadThings keep their references to DontHurtMe in variables declared as IBusinessObject?

Comment: In general, are the business objects cast to the IBusinessIbject when invoking DoBadThings - or is it invoked implicitly???

If implicit, you can use code dom to create a DoBadThings method for each BusinessObject and make the current DoBadThings method private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy.  Write an overload of DoBadThings that takes a DontHurtMe as a parameter.  Now see where it's called.  This won't detect the cases where the method is called with a declared IBusinessObject that *happens* to be a DontHurtMe - but I don't think static analysis can detect that.  This gets all the calls of your method with a *declared* DontHurtMe.

Comment: That _could_ work but `NastyStatic` is in another assembly and doesn't know about `DontHurtMe` per se. I'll try playing around with partial classes to add the overload in `DontHurtMe`'s assembly.

Comment: +1 for elegant solution and indeed, I doubt that static analysis can be smart enough (or if it is at all possible) to cover the cases when the object just happens to be a `DontHurtMe`. If you have some factories or if the interfaces are chained somehow then you're out of luck.

Comment: Agreed, @Carl good plan. My partial class idea didn't work out (I think due to `NastyStatic` using only static methods) but I just stubbed it all out, added the overload, recompiled, and `Find All References` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper 5's **Structural Search** can do this. Supposing the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var hm = new HurtMe();
        var dhm = new DontHurtMe();

        DoBadThings(hm);

        DoBadThings(dhm);

    }

    static void DoBadThings(IBusinessObject ibo) { }
}

interface IBusinessObject { }

class DontHurtMe : IBusinessObject { }

class HurtMe : IBusinessObject { }
```

Now, as noted, a R# `Find Usages` on `DoBadThings`, no matter what options we specify, will find both the invocations in `Main`.

But if we

1. Go to `ReSharper | Find | Search with Pattern....`
2. `Add Placeholder` | `Expression`, name it `dhm` and specify `DontHurtMe` as the type
3. In `Search pattern`, type `DoBadThings($dbm$)`
4. Click Find

we get in our results *only* the invocation of `DoBadThings` on the object with type statically identifiable as a `DontHurtMe`, and *not* the invocation on a `HurtMe`.

---

I do like the neatness of the procedure offered by @Carl Manaster, but this way gives an option for when you can't overload the method in question.

Comment: Ah, nice. I'll remember that if I ever get around to trying R#. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this is a text search (except for the `type` pattern you can use) so you if you have other methods with the same name this might give misleading results. Personally I didn't manage to make it work as expected when trying to find a method call with argument of type X.

Answer (score 0):

I can't come up with solution for static analysis. I just re-examined the options of ReSharper's "Find usages advanced..." and didn't find anything. You could put a condition breakpoint on this method with a condition like `foo is DontHurtMe`, but I suppose you know that already and it's better suited for the cases when you try to locate a bug than for refactoring purposes.

Comment: That's a shame, I had a hunch that ReSharper might be the answer. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: @Ben Scott: or maybe look at NDepend (http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx). I don't have an experience with it but I heard stories about using it for similar tasks